# play list with SoundJS

Tags: javascript, playlist, createjs

I created manifest

```
var manifest = [{src:"song1.ogg", id:"song1"}
           ,{src:"song2.ogg", id:"song2"}
           ,{src:"song3.ogg", id:"song3"}
           ,{src:"buzz.ogg", id:"buzz"}];
```

how I can create infinite play list from song1, song2, song3?

Comment: When you say infinite from 1 to 3, you mean it loops back to 1 after 3?

Comment: yes, song1,song2,song3,song1,...
but don'y play buzz, I need it for playing on some events.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that plays the "next" song, and increments the song index. Listen for the complete event on sounds (onComplete in SoundJS 3 and older, "complete" event in 0.4.0 and newer). When each sound completes, increment the index (reset it if it passes the last index), and play the sound at that index.

Cheers.